# How can I swap values in PyTorch Tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following tensor:

```
vector = torch.tensor([[1,5,3], [2,3,4]])
```

How can I swap values in the second axis?
e.g.

`tensor([[1, 5, 3], [2, 3, 4]])`

becomes:

`tensor([[1, 3, 3], [2, 5, 4]])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use numpy's style of indexing :

```
>>> vector = torch.tensor([[1,5,3], [2,3,4]])
tensor([[1, 3, 4],
        [2, 5, 3]])
>>> vector[[0,1],1] = vector[[1,0],1]
>>> vector 
tensor([[1, 3, 3],
        [2, 5, 4]])
```

In that case, we switch the value between the 0th and 1st index in the first dimension, only at the index 1 on the second dimension.

Comment: Mmm... I see that was lame from my side) thank you so much!